# Inverse Process of the Differential of Multi-variable Functions

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable, such that this integral
> $$\int_{L^+}(x+xy\sin x)dx+\frac{f(x)}{x}dy$$ is independent of the path $L$. Also, $f(\frac{\pi}{2})=0$
> Now I want to find out the function $u(x,y)$ that satisfies
> $$du=(x+xy\sin x)dx+\frac{f(x)}{x}dy$$

My solution is as follows.
First, based on the independence, we have
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\frac{f(x)}{x})=\frac{\partial (x+xy\sin x)}{\partial y}=x\sin x$$

Thus we have
$$f(x)=x(-x\cos x+\sin x-1)$$

Second, for $u(x,y)$ , $x+xy\sin x=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,y)$, namely,

$$u(x,y)=\int{x+xy\sin xdx}+C_1(y)=\frac{1}{2}x^2+y(-x\cos x+\sin x)+C_1(y)$$

Similarly,
$$u(x,y)=\int{\frac{f(x)}{x}dy}=y(-x\cos x+\sin x-1)+C_2(x)$$

Then, we compare these two parts.
$$\frac{1}{2}x^2-yx\cos x+y\sin x+C_1(y)$$
and
$$-yx\cos x+y\sin x-y+C_2(x)$$
We can draw the conclusion that
$C_1(y)=-y+C$
and
$C_2(x)=-\frac{1}{2}x^2+C$?

Finally,
$$u(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}x^2-yx\cos x+y\sin x-y+C$$

Is this process all right?
My teacher's approach is rather a subtle way, which I think is not "universal" way.

His approach is as follows.

$$\begin{align}
du(x,y)&=(x+xy\sin x)dx+(-x\cos x+\sin x-1)dy\\
&=d\frac{x^2}{2}+yd(-x\cos x+\sin x-1)+(-x\cos x+\sin x-1)dy\\
&=d(\frac{x^2}{2}+dy(-x\cos x+\sin x-1))\end{align}$$

I think this is not "universal" because you have to observe the structure of
$$yd(-x\cos x+\sin x-1)+(-x\cos x+\sin x-1)dy$$
which is definitely harder to implement than my way.

However, I do not have steady support of my way presented above, which I do not find any example in my textbooks.
Also, I think that the process of comparing
$$\frac{1}{2}x^2-yx\cos x+y\sin x+C_1(y)$$
and
$$-yx\cos x+y\sin x-y+C_2(x)$$
and draw the conclusion $C_1(y)=-y+C$
and $C_2(x)=-\frac{1}{2}x^2+C$
is not sufficient.

Is any proofs needed here? Also, other approaches welcomed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, both ways are correct. I propose a third approach which in my opinion is simpler.

We are looking for a function $u(x,y)$ such that
$$\begin{cases}
u_x=x+xy\sin(x)\\
u_y=\frac{f(x)}{x}
\end{cases}$$
where $f$ is differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$ and $f(\frac{\pi}{2})=0$.

By integrating the first one with respect to $x$ we get
$$u(x,y)=\frac{x^2}{2}+y(\sin(x)-x\cos(x))+C(y).$$
Putting this in the second one (we avoid the second integration), we get
$$\sin(x)-x\cos(x)+C'(y)=\frac{f(x)}{x}$$
which implies that $C'(y)=c_1$, that is $C(y)=c_1y+c_2$ and therefore
$$f(x)=x(\sin(x)-x\cos(x)+c_1).$$
Since $f(\frac{\pi}{2})=0$, it follows that $c_1=-1$. Hence we find that
$$u(x,y)=\frac{x^2}{2}+y(\sin(x)-x\cos(x)-1)+c_2.$$